# What is a Google AppEngine Instance?

Tags: google-app-engine

What exactly is a Google App Engine Instance as per their plans to change the billing model as they exit preview?

Is an instance a VM with a set of memory and a fixed amount of dedicated CPU power, memory etc or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is an instance a VM with a set of memory and a fixed amount of dedicated CPU power, memory etc or something else?

Yes, exactly that it is. A VM with a set of memory and a fixed amount of dedicated CPU power.
  I can't remember how many instances a google server has but they said that in a I/O session. They also said what kind of servers google is using for App Engine ( quad core with some big amount of ram). Here it's the recording if I'm not wrong https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7B7FyU9wW8Y

Comment: The link doesn't work(I know this answer is more than 3 years old), please update or remove.

Comment: I've updated the link though the server config may not be relevant anymore.

Answer (score 3):

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances.html#Introduction_to_Instances for a general description.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/backends.html for specifics on backends, where you have more control over the resource that you're either reserving or using on demand.

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for something more concrete with respect to the implementation? Are these things just a process or are they a VM?

Comment: -1, In addition of just pointing to (good) resources, you can summarize/extract the relevant answer/section to put as an answer.